# save image using timthumb

Tags: php, timthumb

I am using timthumb to generate the thumbnails. I want the thumbnails to get saved in the specified folder instead of saving them in a cache folder as I want to save the thumbnail image into the database.No caching is required to be done.How can I do this using timthumb or should I prefer this using some other PHP thumbnail library. Which library is suitable for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [WideImage](http://wideimage.sourceforge.net) with quite a lot of success.

It's the best one I've found for what you are looking for.